# Give Wordpress apache user and FTP user write permissions

Tags: wordpress, apache, ftp

Apologies if I am missing something obvious, here is my issue:

1. My employer wants to be able to auto update Wordpress/Plugins from the dashboard using **define('FS_METHOD', 'direct');** in the the wp-config (he doesn't want to run a password-authenticated FTP server). This requires setting the files to be owned by the apache user.
2. My employer also wants to be able to login via SFTP with a key and update files

If I make the files owned by the apache user, he cannot edit them via the SFTP user, and if I make them owned by the SFTP user, apache cannot modify them. I know I can use group permissions, but Wordpress file default is 644 which, if I am correct, means that only the owner can edit the files, not the group.

Is there any solution to this? Thanks!

EDITED: To clarify FTP/SFTP situation

Comment: `" he doesn't want to run an FTP server "` and `" also wants to be able to login via FTP and update files " ` is not exactly logical / possible IMHO...

Comment: @ObmerkKronen Sorry I meant to say, he wants to be able to login via SFTP using a key and edit files, but he does not want to run a standard FTP server with password authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Change the owner to 664 and create the group as you indicated, where is the problem?

Comment: Is making it 664 a security issue in any way (giving group ownership to files)? I just wasn't sure, as most sites I have looked at suggest using 644 as the default for files.